# Server side validation on multiple step form with AJAX PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation

I have a multi-step form (4 steps) which has client side validation using jQuery and uses AJAX to process form inputs.
On every next button click my JS validation is run.

But client side validation is not good enough. I would like to setup server side validation too.

So I prefer using AJAX to server side validate the form as it allows same UX as client side validation. I would like to use the instructions here:
http://fearlessflyer.com/how-to-ajax-validate-forms/

But how can I follow the similar scripts from that post for a multi-step wizard form rather than a simple form?

1. Should every next button of a step be a post to do server side validation and process field's inline error in the current step?
2. Or should the form be posted for server side validation at the final confirmation 4th step? 
   How can the relevant form steps with inline errors be shown when validating form fields right at the last step?

I'm using plain PHP on server side without any frameworks.

Comment: Would it be wise to go for both 1st & 2nd options? Also is the method described by the linked post advisable to use?

Comment: If this is a "multi-step wizard" then, for sake of the client, you should probably validate on the server per every time you move to the next step. Who wants to reach the end, click submit, then find out they have to back track a few steps in order to fix a problem? This means validating via the submit button per each individual section, then returning error messages as appropriate.

Comment: Yes that is what I thought too. But would it be wise to server side validate on last step too? Because the form data is transferred with AJAX, at the last step can't someone edit the form data just before submitting on last step for DB processing?

Comment: That is the main reason why you would want to validate server-side, in case someone altered the data. Front end validation is only meant to mitigate as many issues as possible, not completely prevent them. The server is where you should attempt to prevent as many issues as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your POST Request should be at the 4th and final step of the validation. All the steps should already be loaded onto the HTML Page, you can use javascript to show section by section.

You can have "inline" validation using the onblur="" HTML attribute. The function inside is called when the user unfocuses the input box.

For Ex:
`<input type="text" onblur="validate()">`

Comment: But this is using client side validation (using JS) rather than server side validation?

Comment: You can also validate it on the server too ! Since all the HTML is loaded onto 1 page

Answer (score 1):

It depends on you. Both solutions seems good for me. However, client-side validation may be enough for a regular user. And if someone wants to mess with your code, then the server-side validation at the end of the process will stop him from doing so. You can then rewind to the first step that may contain errors and display them.

Comment: Yes but how do I follow the scripts as in the linked post to do server side validation on a multi-step form? It is not so straightfoward with multistep form. In terms showing the in errors for the fields in each step

Comment: Ok yes, how can i display the 1st step fields with errors after posting at the end (if there are validation errors)?

Comment: How is your multi-step form built? Is every step a different page or just a different sections displayed one after another?

Comment: Every step is just a different section displayed one after another. So form steps are all in 1 page. 4 Steps are arranged in 4 divs, and displayed and hidden by JS offcourse.

Comment: Ok, so at the end you can validate full form server-side, apply styles and descriptions for all wrong fields and then display the first section of your form where the error was found. I don't know your code so I can't tell you how to do it.